# software bricked android 7

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, unbricking, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G (xt1032) and few weeks ago I tried to install cm14.1. But somewhere it didn't work. Since then I cannot boot.
And I can't install a new custom rom. 
I have Cyanogenmod Recovery. When I try to use fastboot/adb it did not work. because the device is unauthorized. 
The only thing that is working is adb sideload. But when I tried to install a custom rom a error happend:

```
This package is for device: xt1032, ...
this device is .
```

I tried to remove the assert command from updater-script, but when I reziped the file and tried to install it, a signature validation error occurred.

Comment: CM Recovery has signature verification on (by default). FFS, ditch Cyanogen Recovery and use TWRP already. Let CM Recovery die for its own sin.

Comment: and how should I install it? the adb/fastboot commands won't work, because it says the device is unauthorized. and i can't boot the device and authrorize it

Comment: Of course fastboot commands won't work in recovery - restart to bootloader and use them, no authorization required (but you do need to sort out driver issues if any).

Comment: thanks a lot. under windows my device wasn't discouvered, altough i had installed the universal adb driver. Then I tried it under linux and everything just worked :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, hard-bricks are the rare write-offs.

For the vast majority of soft-bricked devices (FRP errors, blocked custom binaries, etc) the following can erase the device and reinstall the orginal firmware ([Samsung example](https://www.xda-developers.com/download-stock-odin-firmware-samfirm/) given below). Alternatively, install TWRP and [latest AOSP firmware](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-android-oreo-samsung-galaxy-s7-exynos/).

**These instructions are for experienced technicians. Proceed with due caution.**

- Backup your existing firmware (optional, if permitted by brick)
- Download **latest** version of [Odin](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2711451) to a WIN10 computer.
- Enable BL, AP, CSC, etc firmware types in Odin.ini
- Download [SamFirm](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/general/tool-samfirm-samsung-firmware-t2988647) (or visit [Updato](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model) - generic firmware) to fetch from Samsung's firmware archives by providing **EXACT** model/provider (eg. SM-G935W8/BMC = S7Edge/BellMob)
- Extract BL, AP, CSC, firmware (*.tar.MD5)  from firmware archive
- Connect mobile device to WIN10 computer with USB data cable.
- From off, PWR+VOLDWN+HOME to enter bootloader.
- Load firmware in Odin and hit start (do NOT change defaults)
- Device firmware will be erased and flashed with new firmware.